# How to make a crossword in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to all this javascript, I was trying to make a crossword. I want a webpage that automatically makes 485 divs inside another div when the page loads. How is it possible to do this with a for loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741006/adding-div-element-to-body-or-document-in-javascript and http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Answer (score 4):

http://jsbin.com/nazuwoqe/1/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myContainer"></div>
  <script>
    var element;
    var body = document.getElementById('myContainer');
    for(var i=0; i<485; i++) {
      element = document.createElement("div");
      element.innerHTML = i;
      body.appendChild(element);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Point for you, but its hard to give someone slack when its an insanely easy question to Google.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var BigDiv = document.createElement('div');
// specify BigDiv's param like id, class etc. here

var TinyDiv;

for (i = 0; i < 485; i++) {

    TinyDiv = document.createElement('div');
    // specify TinyDiv's param like id, class etc. here
    BigDiv.appendChild(TinyDiv)
}

//put your BigDiv where you want to, here it's in body
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(BigDiv);
```

Comment: Don't use `var` in a loop!!

Comment: I thought you *was* supposed to use `var` in a loop?? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5717233/2826653