# For loop index variable modified with helper method?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm using the following for loop and as it is written below it alerts **0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8** (like it should) but when I uncomment `set(buttons, i)` it alerts **0, 2, 4, 6, 8**.

```
for(i = 0; i < layerOrder.length; i++){
    alert(i);
    //set(buttons, i);
}
```

I'm very confused by this behavior because I have always assumed that integers were passed by value and not reference.

Is it possible to modify the for loop index variable in a function method like in my `set()` method? If so I can focus my time on debugging that.

Comment: primitives are passed by value. what's the code of `set()`? does it use a variable `i`? have you declared it inside the function?

Comment: The code that you've provided in your question won't reproduce the problem you're having.  You probably ought to declare `i` in the `for` loop itself, rather than referencing a global variable `i`.

Comment: There's quite a bit of code involved to reproduce the problem. I followed it back to this for loop but I understand now it was a question of scope. Adding `var i = 0` did actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like something that is caused by leaving out the var. Please update your first line to read:

```
for(var i = 0; i < layerOrder.length; i++){
```

Please refer to this page for more info: ["var" or no "var" in JavaScript's "for-in" loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717126/var-or-no-var-in-javascripts-for-in-loop)

Comment: Also the `set` function needs to declare `i` as a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

You must be incrementing `i` in set method.

Since you have not described `i` as local variable by prefixing `var` keyword it is treated as a global variable in `for` loop.
And hence is modified in set method.
In javascript to declare a variable locally prefix it with `var` or else they are defined as global variables.