# Dimple Tooltip Add custom text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I am building a chart with dimple js and tryin to adjust the tooltip. I figured out how to add the "Gender" and "Survival Rate". Now I want to add the survival count that is stored in the flatgroups object. How can I do this? Below effort (with a for loop) does not seem to work. It gives me an error saying the flatgroups object is undefined and it cannot take the length of an undefined object. Thanks!

```
 function draw_bar(data) {
  var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chart1", 800, 600);

// Group/nest data by gender and calculate survival rate and number of people that survived per gender 
var grouped_data = d3.nest()
                .key(function (d) {return d.Sex;})
                .rollup(function (v) {return {"Survival Rate": d3.mean(v, 
                                                                        function (d) {
                                                                            return d.Survived;
                                                                                     }
                                                                      ), 
                                              "Survival Count": d3.sum(v, 
                                                                        function (d) {
                                                                            return d.Survived;
                                                                                     }
                                                                      )
                                             };
                                     }
                        )
                .entries(data);

  // flatten the data structure stored in grouped_data
   var flatgroups = [];
   grouped_data.forEach(function (group) {
            flatgroups.push({
                        "Gender": group.key,
                        "Survival Rate": group.values["Survival Rate"],
                        "Survival Count": group.values["Survival Count"] 
                        });
                  });

  // Construct chart, set axis labels and draw it
  var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, flatgroups);
  var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Gender");
  x.title = "Gender";
  var y = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Survival Rate");
  y.title = "Survival Rate";
  // Format y-axis to show proportions with 2 decimals
  y.tickFormat = ',.2f';
  var series = chart.addSeries("Gender", dimple.plot.bar);
  series.getTooltipText = function (e) {
                        var key = e.key;
                         for (i in flatgroups) {
                            if (i.key == key) {
                                return [ "Gender" + ": " + e.cx,
                     "Survival Rate" + ": " + (e.cy).toFixed(2),
                     "Survival Count" + ": " + i["Survival Count"]

                                        ];
                                                            };
                         };
  };
  chart.assignColor("female", "red")
  chart.assignColor("male", "blue")
  chart.draw();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flatgroups` is an array of objects. When you iterate over it with `for (i in flatgroups)`, what you're iterating over are the integer array keys. In other words, the values of `i` in this for loop will be `0`, `1`, etc.

What you can do here is just add a line like `var group = flatgroups[i];` as your first line inside the `for` loop. Then use `group` (the actual group object) to refer to the group instead of `i` (the integer key).

I suspect as well that you'll need to change the line `if (i.key == key)` to something more like `if (group.Gender == key)`, as `key` doesn't appear to be one of the actual keys in the objects you created.

Comment: You may also want to make that `for (var i in flatgroups)` instead of `for (i in flatgroups)`. See [“var” or no “var” in JavaScript's “for-in” loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717126).