# Declaring variables inside or outside in a for-in loop

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, variables, declaration

Having this two options:

Option A:

```
var index;
for (index in myObject) {
  // Do something
}
```

Option B:

```
for (var index in myObject) {
  // Do something
}
```

I don't know if in the option B the variable `index` it's being redeclared every time of the loop or just once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those two snippets of code do exactly the same thing (and that's the case in most language such as C, C++ and C# amongst others). If the variable was redeclared at every iteration, then following your logic, it would also be re-initialized, and would constantly loop over the same object. Your loop would be infinite.

On a side-note, in JavaScript, all variable declarations get pushed to the function scope; this means that you can declare variables anywhere within a function, even within nested loops, and they will only be declared once.

[Link to the var documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

[Relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684923/javascript-variables-declare-outside-or-inside-loop)

[Other relevant SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5717276/2700737)

Edit courtesy of @torazaburo:

If you want to declare a variable with a local scope (as in, a variable that will only be defined in the current block such as a `for`, `while` or `if`, you can use the `let` statement:

```
let var1 = 123;
```

It also allows you to override variables with the same name but declared in a higher scope, such as in this example from the docs:

```
function letTest() {
    let x = 1;
    if (true) {
        let x = 2;  // different variable
        console.log(x);  // 2
    }
    console.log(x);  // 1
}
```

See the full documentation (and examples) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

Comment: It would seem highly useful to include in this answer how `let` works in this context.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred approach in 2016 is to declare the variable in the loop head, using `let`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) { }
     ^^^
```

There is probably minimal performance difference between this and other approaches, but there are major advantages in terms of the robustness and clarity of your code.

First, with `let`, `i` is local to the `for` construct, so it can't "leak out", or modify some other `i` in an outer scope.

Second, and perhaps more importantly, a new version of `i` is created for each iteration of the loop. In technical terms, "you get a fresh **binding** for each iteration if you let-declare a variable" (see [this excellent article](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html)). This solves the age-old problem of closures created inside the for-loop using the final value of `i`. We can now just write

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => alert(i), i * 1000);
}
```

instead of having to do some clumsy work-around such as

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(() => alert(i), i * 1000);
  }(i));
}
```

which has been the topic of countless questions here on SO, and which many of you have wasted far too many brain cycles learning.