# Looping inside an object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I had encountered something unclear to me in the for loop:

```
var info = {
"full_name" : "John Doe",
"title" : "FrontEnd",
"links" : {
    "blog"     : "JohnDoe.com",
    "facebook" : "http://facebook.com/JohnDoe",
        "youtube"  : "http://www.youtube.com/JohnDoe",
        "twitter"  : "http://twitter.com/JohnDoe" 
    }
};
```

I'm looping through this object with this loop:

```
var output = "";

for (var key in info.links ) {
    if (info.links.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        output += '<li>' +
        '<a href = "' + info.links[key] +
        '">' + key + '</a>' +
        '</li>';
        console.log(key);
    } 
}
var update = document.getElementById('links');
update.innerHTML = output;
```

And my question is, what is var key in this loop and why it works when there is no var key in scope of this loop? In this case var key becomes blog, facebook etc. inside info.links object. But why?

Comment: Consider this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465211/javascript-loop-variable-scope

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717126/var-or-no-var-in-javascripts-for-in-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go thorough this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

```
for (variable in object) { ...
}
```

Variable "A different property name is assigned to variable on each iteration."
In your case "facebook", "twitter" , etc are your property names in object

Answer (score 0):

`var` means that you're declaring a new variable, `key` is the name you give this variable.

Since you're looping through everthing in `info.links` you want to be able to call each `var` individually

Answer (score 0):

Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object) for a sample solution. The `key` represents the keys of the info.links object say `blog, facebook` etc, thus `info.links[key]` represents the value i.e,

```
info.links["blog"] = "JohnDoe.com", 
info.links["facebook"] = "http://facebook.com/JohnDoe"
```

Hope this is clear.

Look this link for [**loop**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) description

Comment: I know what it represents but what it is? Is it some kind of default object like event object while handling events in DOM?

Comment: What object are you asking?