# Javascript get object name

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an object... Ho can I retrieve its name

```
var data = {
  "FORD": {
    "PK RANGER": ["2012", "2013"],
    "PJ RANGER": ["2010", "2011"]
  },
  "HONDA": {
    "CRV": ["2007", "2008", "2009"]
  }
}

console.log(data.FORD);
```

`data.FORD` displays data inside it...

```
[object Object] {
  PJ RANGER: ["2010", "2011"],
  PK RANGER: ["2012", "2013"]
}
```

Is there a way where i can display its name like: `FORD`?

Comment: for (key in data){
}

Comment: Object.keys(data).forEach(console.log);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for loop for this. Like:

```js
var data = {
  "FORD": {
    "PK RANGER": ["2012", "2013"],
    "PJ RANGER": ["2010", "2011"]
  },
  "HONDA": {
    "CRV": ["2007", "2008", "2009"]
  }
}
for (var i in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to add `var` keyword in for? can I write it like `for(i in data)`?

Comment: You can but its advised to always use a `var`, to limit the `i` variable's scope. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717126/var-or-no-var-in-javascripts-for-in-loop) out to get a better understanding.

Comment: Also can I add loop inside the loop to get the sub objects name? Like PK RANGER and PJ RANGER?

Comment: Yes since the sub objects are objects themselves, you can loop through them like above.

Comment: I tried but it shows me "0" "1" "2" .... http://jsbin.com/weqevug/edit?js,console

Comment: How did you try it?

Comment: Is my object defined properly ... I think something not right in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143597/discussion-between-omer-and-gaganshera).