# Is there a difference between `for (item of array)` and `for (let item of array)`?

Tags: javascript

This is just a question, didn't find the answer while searching in MDN or stackoverflow. The two statements

`for (let item of array)` and `for (item of array)` seems to work exactly the same. Are they equivalent (i.e. is the variable **item** implicitly declared with `let` if nothing precedes it)?

Edit:
This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717126/var-or-no-var-in-javascripts-for-in-loop) - the difference is that this specifically asks about the for..of loop, and the answers that deal with the `let` keywords are towards the bottom so that may get missed. But both questions are about the same concept. The gist is below:

1. If a variable is not declared explicitly within for, it is considered a global variable (if not declared before, within the same function).
2. If it is declared with `var`, it is local to the function in which declared.
3. If it is declared with `let`, it is only local to the for block.

Comment: It would likely depend on which version of JavaScript/EMCAScript you're targeting, and whether you've enabled strict mode.

Comment: `let` explicitely declares a block-scoped variabe. Without, the loop still iterates a variable `item` but it assumes that it has been declared beforehand. If not, it creates a global variable or crashes in strict mode.

Comment: `let` has blocked scope, so `item` can only be used within the for loop, `item` alone isn't defined to the scope of the loop itself: https://jsfiddle.net/e17Lkwx0/ (there are more differences though (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35812376/5648954)))

Comment: Also, you might find this to be a useful read: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-declare-variables-javascript/

Comment: Read about the [`let` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables#The_difference_between_var_and_let) in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not use let or var in the loop, you create a variable in the global scope

The `var` stays defined only in the function

The `let` stays defined only in the loop statement

```js
const arr = ["One","Two","Three"]
function test1() {
  for (var a of arr) console.log(a);
  console.log("var a after loop:",a) // works
}  

function test2() {
  for (let b of arr) console.log(b);
  console.log("trying to log `let b` after loop")
  try {
    console.log("let b after loop:",b); // fails  
  }
  catch(e) { console.log("Error:",e.message)}
}  

function test3() {
  for (c of arr) console.log(c);
  console.log("'global' c after loop:",c) //works 
}  


test1(); 
test2(); 
test3(); 

// fails
console.log("Trying to log var a after function")
try { console.log("var a after function:",a);}
catch(e) { console.log("Error:",e.message)}  
console.log("Trying to log let b after function")
try { console.log("b after function:",b);}
catch(e) { console.log("Error:",e.message)}

console.log("'global' c after function:",c); // logs
```

Answer (score 0):

They are equivalent functionally. But this is not a good practice to do so.
Make sure to use `let` or `var` as it will prevent you from getting weird bugs or issues if your code gets large, as simply using `item` is creating or referring to a global variable. It is a time bomb