# Can I use for loop iterator as an array index in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Javascript For loop not working while using the iterator (i) as an array index

```
boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("menoe");
imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("course_image");
butns = document.getElementsByClassName("continue_learning");
function meraj (imgs, butns, i) {
  imgs[i].style.opacity = "0.1";
  butns[i].style.visibility = "visible";
}
function merajo (imgs, butns, i) {
  imgs[i].style.opacity = "1";
  butns[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
}
for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  boxes[i].addEventListener("mouseover", meraj(imgs, butns, i));
  boxes[i].addEventListener("mouseout", merajo(imgs, butns, i));
}
```

Comment: Are you suer that ```document.getElementsByClassName("menoe");``` returns more than one element  ?

Comment: Curser as array index? Looks like you are using 'i' as the index. Also by not working, what is the issue you are getting?

Comment: Yes it returns many elements, I have checked it and it does not even work on the first one

Comment: @Spangle 
i is the cursor in for loop and also passed as an argument to functions inside the loop
It does not give any errors in the console as undefined or smth like that, just not working

Comment: add ```console.log(boxes.length)``` and check will it log more than 1

Comment: @KrzysztofKaczyński It says 31

Comment: So now add ```console.log(i)``` inside this for loop if it prints ```i``` 31 times it means that a problem is not with for loop

Comment: Yes, it prints i from 0 to 30

Comment: So it is not a problem with for loop.  You should change the question because now I do not know what is your problem and how can I help you

Comment: I think the problem is about the possibility of passing a variable as an array index in Javascript

Comment: By the way, you should see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717126/var-or-no-var-in-javascripts-for-in-loop

Comment: @Hektor , Thanks I finally found that the problem is with the addEventListener method in javascript, the second argument can include only the name of the call function without any parenthesis or parameters. I have figured out a solutionand posted it in my answer below. Tell me what do you think.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem and this is the final solution:

```
meraj = function meraj (imgs, butns, i) {
  imgs[i].style.opacity = "0.1";
  butns[i].style.visibility = "visible";
}
merajo = function merajo (imgs, butns, i) {
  imgs[i].style.opacity = "1";
  butns[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
}
function addListenerWithArgs(elem, evt, func, var1, var2, var3){
  var f = function(ff, v1, v2, v3){
    return (function (){
      ff(v1, v2, v3);
    });
  }(func, var1, var2, var3);
  elem.addEventListener(evt, f);
  return f;
}
for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  var storeFunc = addListenerWithArgs(boxes[i], "mouseover", meraj, imgs, butns, i);
  var storeFunc = addListenerWithArgs(boxes[i], "mouseout", merajo, imgs, butns, i);
}
```